# Multitasking with MPMediaPlayer

Tags: streaming, xcode4.2, avaudioplayer, multitasking, mpmediaplayercontroller

I'm streaming and playing an MP3 file in a MPMediaPlayer. I've been looking for solutions, and I saw ways to do it with an AVAudioPlayer, but I need to use the MediaPlayer. Is it possible to have it Multitask and be able to be controlled from the multitasking menu?

I already added the stuff in the info.plist, btw.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using `applicationMusicPlayer`?

`applicationMusicPlayer` doesn't run in background.

`iPodMusicPlayer` of MPMusicPlayer can run in background like apple's Music app.